# Mostrar div e esconder a que estava ou foi aberta anteriormente, ao clicar em botão <a>

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
@foreach($user->endereco as $endereco)
   <table class="table">
      <thead class="thead-light">
         <tr>
            <th scope="row">Endereço: {{ $endereco->endereco }}</th>
            <th scope="row">Número: {{ $endereco->numero }}</th>
            <th scope="row"><small><a onclick="showendereco();" id="{{ $endereco->id }}">Mostrar Tudo</a></small></th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
   </table>
   <div class="endereco end-{{ $endereco->id }}" style="display: none;">
      <table class="table">
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <th scope="row">complemento:</th>
               <td>{{ $endereco->complemento }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <th scope="row">Bairro:</th>
               <td>{{ $endereco->bairro }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <th scope="row">Cidade:</th>
               <td>{{ $endereco->cidade }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <th scope="row">Estado:</th>
               <td>{{ $endereco->estado }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <th scope="row">Ponto de Referência:</th>
               <td>{{ $endereco->referencia }}</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
@endforeach
```

Tenho essa listagem de endereço, mostrando apenas um pedaço do endereço, com um botão para mostrar o restante dos dados.

quero que quando um endereço estiver expandido, e caso seja clicado em outro endereço, o que já estava expandido entre em hidden e o clicado seja aberto.

pode ter 1 endereço.. pode ter 2.. 5... etc.. preciso que mostre apenas 1 quando clicado nele.

Comment: tipo esse [collapsible](https://materializecss.com/collapsible.html)

Comment: Exatamente @GuilhermeCostamilam porém em Jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em vez de usar uma função para isso (`onclick="showendereco();"`), pode simplesmente colocar uma classe (`class="mostratudo"`) e criar um evento que irá detectar pela classe quando o botão foi clicado, e abrir a respectiva `div` baseando-se no `id` do botão, já que cada `div` está relacionada a seu botão pela classe `.end-ID_DO_BOTÃO`.

**Exemplo** (demais explicações no código):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   
   $(".mostratudo").click(function(){
      
      // pega a respectiva div onde possui a classe "end-" + o id do botão clicado
      var comp = $("div.end-"+this.id);

      if(comp.is(":visible")){ // se a div estiver visível, oculta ela
         comp.hide();
      }else{ // caso contrário, oculta todas as divs e mostra a do botão clicado
         $(".endereco:visible").hide();
         comp.show();
      }

   });
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
   <thead class="thead-light">
      <tr>
         <th scope="row">Endereço: {{ $endereco->endereco }}</th>
         <th scope="row">Número: {{ $endereco->numero }}</th>
         <th scope="row"><small><a class="mostratudo" id="1">Mostrar Tudo</a></small></th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
</table>
<div class="endereco end-1" style="display: none;">
   <table class="table">
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <th scope="row">complemento:</th>
            <td>{{ $endereco->complemento }}</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th scope="row">Bairro:</th>
            <td>{{ $endereco->bairro }}</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th scope="row">Cidade:</th>
            <td>{{ $endereco->cidade }}</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th scope="row">Estado:</th>
            <td>{{ $endereco->estado }}</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th scope="row">Ponto de Referência:</th>
            <td>{{ $endereco->referencia }}</td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>

<table class="table">
   <thead class="thead-light">
      <tr>
         <th scope="row">Endereço: {{ $endereco->endereco }}</th>
         <th scope="row">Número: {{ $endereco->numero }}</th>
         <th scope="row"><small><a class="mostratudo" id="2">Mostrar Tudo</a></small></th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
</table>
<div class="endereco end-2" style="display: none;">
   <table class="table">
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <th scope="row">complemento:</th>
            <td>{{ $endereco->complemento }}</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th scope="row">Bairro:</th>
            <td>{{ $endereco->bairro }}</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th scope="row">Cidade:</th>
            <td>{{ $endereco->cidade }}</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th scope="row">Estado:</th>
            <td>{{ $endereco->estado }}</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th scope="row">Ponto de Referência:</th>
            <td>{{ $endereco->referencia }}</td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Direto na jugular.. top mano!!! resolveu o problema e aprendi como faz o//
obrigado brother!! vlw