# Div1 desaparecer e div2 aparecer ao clicar no botão

Tags: php, javascript

Boa Noite, estou com um pequeno problema, na verdade não sei resolver sou iniciante rs, eu to tenho duas tabelas em duas divs diferentes, uma fica visivel div1 e outra invisivel div2 e ao clicar no botão eu escondo a div visivel(div1) e mostro a div invisivel(div2) com a nova consulta do banco, só que quando clico no botão a pagina dá refresh,e a div2 que deveria aparecer ela fica por dois segundos na tela e some, e volta a aparecer a visivel(div1) do inicio. Como eu faço que mesmo com o refresh quando clicar no botão a div invisivel(div2) aparece e a outra visivel(div1) desapareça. Quem puder me ajudar agradeço. Meu codigo está assim:

```
<style>
#div2{display:none;}
</style>

<script>
  function ocultar(){
        document.getElementById("div1").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("div2").style.display = "block";
      }

</script>

//botão de trazer consulta do banco e ocultar e mostrar as div
 <button type="submit" onclick="ocultar();">Buscar</button>

<div id="div1">//essa div fica visivel</div>

<div id="div2">//essa div fica invisivel, e ao clicar no botão a div1
```

deveria sumir e aparecer somente essa com a consulta do banco, só que com o 
refresh ela aparece por dois segundos some, e volta a aparecer a div1

Comment: dê uma procurada no site que provavelmente vai achar alguma pergunta que te ajude, essa dúvida é bem comum por aqui, como essa pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/316922/57220

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu botão é do tipo submit. Sempre que você clicar ele vai dar um refresh na página e carregar tudo do jeitinho que você escreveu. Para consultar o banco sem carregar a página você pode utilizar AJAX.

Comment: haa entendi, vou tentar fazer aqui, mto obrigado.

Comment: Obrigado sua dica funcionou, consegui resolver aqui.